# Unknown error in function to convert decimal to binary

Tags: python

I wrote code to convert decimal to binary. I think it is not wrong but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

decimal == o and decimal > 0

```
def binary_converter(decimal_number):
    # ================================

    i = decimal_number
    if i == 0 :
        result = '0'
    else :
        while i > 0:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                result = result + '0'
                i = i//2
            else :
                result = result + '1'
                i = i//2
    #==================================
    return result.strip()
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected output and what are you getting? What are the errors?

Answer (score 3):

There are two correctness issues:

1. You need to declare and initialize `result`.
2. `result = result + '0'` appends to the wrong side of the string, reversing the output. Use `result = '0' + result` or reverse the result manually before returning. Appending to a string repeatedly in a loop can suffer from [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).

Here's a simple re-write:

```
def binary_converter(i):
    result = ""

    while i: 
        result = str(i % 2) + result
        i //= 2

    return result if result else "0"
```

Here's a re-write using lists:

```
def binary_converter(i):
    result = []

    while i: 
        result.append(i % 2)
        i >>= 1

    return "".join(map(str, result)) if result else "0"
```

Or use the builtin function [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin). Use `bin(42)[2:]` if you need to chop off the `0b` prefix.

Note that none of these functions take negative numbers into consideration.

Comment: A caveat for `bin`: if you pass a negative number, the prefix becomes `-0b`, so the `bin(42)[2:]` trick only works for numbers that are zero or greater. (Of course, this is not a problem in the OP's case, since they specify zero or greater as a precondition.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't technically answering your question, but just in case you didn't know, Python has built-in functionality for converting numbers to binary string representations.

With [bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin):

```
bin(3)  # "0b11"
```

With [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
format(3, "b")  # "11"
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try below code

```
def binary_converter(decimal_number):
  i = decimal_number
  result='0'  # define variable before use and used string instead int
  if i > 0 :
      while i > 0:
          if i % 2 == 0:
              result = result + '0'
              i = i//2
          else :
              result = result + '1'
              i = i//2
  return result.strip()
```

Also please post error you are getting. it helps to debug.
Thanks,

Comment: There seems to be a bug in here: `binary_converter(2)` produces "001" and `binary_converter(6)` produces "0011".